# GET request on an AWS API in React

Tags: reactjs, api, amazon-web-services, cors

I am trying to access an AWS API via a simple react app, but I'm getting a CORS error. All I want to do is access the data, and then display it and allow users to organize it. When I plug the url of the data into my browser, the information displays perfectly.

My API file looks as such:

```
const beerURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/....";

//Grab all the data from the API so we can use it in our application
export default {
searchBeer: () => {
   return fetch(beerURL)
 }
}
```

In my App.js file, I'm making the call as such:

```
import API from "./utils/API";

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    beer: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData = () => {
  Promise.all([
    API.searchBeer()
  ])
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ beer: response });
  })

}

render() {
  ...

}
```

Is this something I need to set up a CORS server for? I don't understand why I would need to do that for a simple GET request.

Comment: Please try to disable chrome web security. As you're tryung to access cross domain url.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala, I tried in another browser and I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Yes. Its because of the same reason.

Comment: This might help
https://www.moxio.com/blog/12/how-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-in-javascript-using-cors

Comment: Can you show your API.js ?

Comment: @Prabhu, what I have in the API.js is in the first code block above

Answer (score 0):

same-origin only succeeds for requests for assets on the same origin, all other requests will reject.

cors will allow requests for assets on the same-origin and other origins which return the appropriate CORs headers.

cors-with-forced-preflight will always perform a preflight check before making the actual request.

no-cors is intended to make requests to other origins that do not have CORS headers and result in an opaque response, but as stated, this isn't possible in the window global scope at the moment.

To define the mode, add an options object as the second parameter in the fetch request and define the mode in that object:

```
fetch('http://some-site.com/cors-enabled/some.json', {mode: 'cors'})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    console.log('Request successful', text);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    log('Request failed', error)
  });
```

Comment: this still did not solve the issue. I've been running with a chrome plug in, but even though it's deployed, I can't access the API. I'm a third party user

Answer (score 0):

That API appears to be permissive, responding with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

I haven't figured out what is causing your problem, but I don't think it is simply the fetch API.

You can change your code like below

```
const beerURL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/....";

fetch(beerURL)
   .then( response => response.json() )
   .then( data => console.log(data) )
```